# How to store request data of post requests on an nginx server?

Tags: python, mongodb, nginx, webserver, fluentd

I have a python application running on an gunicorn server which is behind a nginx server. A post request with JSON data hits the nginx server, which then forwards it to gunicorn server. There is a requirement of maintaining the request data in mongodb database. I have tried using Fluentd to directly read the access.log(custom format) of nginx and store it in mongodb collection.
There are several challenges in doing this using fluentd, like parsing the request input using custom parser, managing multiple databases and it's also a bit slower.
Is there any method to directly store request data from nginx to mongodb database.

Comment: Why dont you do it in the request handler of the Python application.

Comment: Because the nginx server acts as a load balancer here. I cannot remove nginx